# Checkbox should populate textbox from array but doesn't work every time

Tags: arrays, vba, checkbox, text

I have a userform which has 2 tabs and each has 2 frames where in each frame has 6 to 7 checkboxes. I also have an array of values for the checkboxes.

When I click a checkbox I want it to populate the textbox with the array value that corresponds to that checkbox.

This works properly the first time a click a checkbox, but doesn't work a second time.

I am getting the corresponding value but only on the third click and then all checkboxes begin to work, then if I stop and restart again the checkbox whichever I choose works only from the 3rd click.

Thanks very much!

```
Public strArrPositiveNote(3) As String

Sub DisplayManager()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control, txt As String
    txt = vbNullString
    MyForm.TextBox2.Value = txt
    For Each ctrl In MyForm.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctrl.Value Then
                txt = txt & GetMessage(ctrl.Name) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    strArrPositiveNote(0) = "First note"
    strArrPositiveNote(1) = "Second note"
End Sub

Function GetMessage(cbName As String) As String
    Dim str As String
    If cbName = "CheckBox1" Then
        str = "first note" '''''''''''''''''--- works for this
        str = strArrPositiveNote(6)
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox2" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(2)
        ' str = "two"
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox3" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(0)
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox4" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(5)
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox5" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(1)
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox6" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(3)
    ElseIf cbName = "CheckBox7" Then
        str = strArrPositiveNote(4)
    End If
    GetMessage = str
End Function
```

Comment: What' it doing? An error? What happens from the second click?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am getting the corresponding value but only on the third click and then all checkboxes begin to work ,then if i stop and restart again the checkbox whichever i choose works only from the 3rd click

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow!*  I've tidied up the question to make it more clear (and therefore more likely to get multiple answers). You can always roll-back or re-[edit] the change if you don't like it (...or anyone's posts if you so choose!)

Comment: BTW you declare `strArrPositiveNote(3) As String` but then your code tries to access that array with indexes up to 6!

Comment: no this was just to show.  i have declared the whole array in my copy.

Comment: well, show the right code to have the right help! Moreover, you say -"When I click a checkbox"-, so why don't you use Checkbox Click event?

Answer (score 0):

`strArrPositiveNote()` should be replaced Dictionary. Arrays are good at storing values by index.  A Dictionary should be used to store values by name.

It appear that the order of operation is wrong.

```
Sub DisplayManager()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control, txt As String

    strArrPositiveNote(0) = "First note"

    strArrPositiveNote(1) = "Second note"

    For Each ctrl In MyForm.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctrl.Value Then
                txt = txt & GetMessage(ctrl.Name) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    MyForm.TextBox2.Value = txt

End Sub
```

Here are some alternate ways to write `GetMessage`.

### GetMessage: Select Case

```
Function GetMessage(cbName As String) As String
    Select Case cbName
    Case "CheckBox1"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(6)
    Case "CheckBox2"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(2)
    Case "CheckBox3"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(0)
    Case "CheckBox4"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(5)
    Case "CheckBox5"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(1)
    Case "CheckBox6"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(3)
    Case "CheckBox7"
        GetMessage = strArrPositiveNote(4)
    End Select

End Function
```

### GetMessage:Switch Function

```
Function GetMessage(cbName As String) As String
    GetMessage = Switch("CheckBox1", strArrPositiveNote(6), _
                        "CheckBox2", strArrPositiveNote(2), _
                        "CheckBox3", strArrPositiveNote(0), _
                        "CheckBox4", strArrPositiveNote(5), _
                        "CheckBox5", strArrPositiveNote(1), _
                        "CheckBox6", strArrPositiveNote(3), _
                        "CheckBox7", strArrPositiveNote(4))

End Function
```

### GetMessage:Dictionary

```
Function GetMessage(cbName As String) As Object
    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dic.Add "CheckBox1", strArrPositiveNote(6)
    dic.Add "CheckBox2", strArrPositiveNote(2)
    dic.Add "CheckBox3", strArrPositiveNote(0)
    dic.Add "CheckBox4", strArrPositiveNote(5)
    dic.Add "CheckBox5", strArrPositiveNote(1)
    dic.Add "CheckBox6", strArrPositiveNote(3)
    dic.Add "CheckBox7", strArrPositiveNote(4)

    Set GetMessage = dic(cbName)
End Function
```

Comment: The select case worked whereas switch dictionary gave errors

Comment: I modified the Dictionary.  What you should have is a class level dictionary that you track the values with.